# Android: Can't parse null values from SOAP response (kSoap2)

Tags: android, parsing, soap, null

When parsing the SoapObject data into a String[], the empty fields in the response from the webservice do not get added to it and I can't identify the empty propeties by checking for null or "".

So my problem is basically: The SoapObject contains the right amount of properties, but the parsed result (String[]) does not contain the ones that are empty, nor can I check for empty properties and add "" to the String[].

This causes problems for me when saving to the SQLite DB since every e.g. "User" contains a different amount of fields.

```
public static String[] getStringArrayResponse(SoapObject node, Vector<String> strings) {

    boolean isFirstCall = false;

    if (strings == null) {
        isFirstCall = true;
        strings = new Vector<String>();
    }

    int count = node.getPropertyCount(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        Object obj1 = node.getProperty(i);

        if (obj1 instanceof SoapObject) {
            if (((SoapObject)obj1).getPropertyCount() > 0) {
                // Returns the correct amount of properties
                Log.d("PARSER", "propertycount = " +((SoapObject)obj1).getPropertyCount());
                getStringArrayResponse((SoapObject)obj1, strings);
            }
        } else if (obj1 instanceof SoapPrimitive) { 
            strings.add(((SoapPrimitive)obj1).toString());
        } 
    }

    if (isFirstCall) {
        return (String[])strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]);
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is really giving me a headache and I'm grateful for any help I can get :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to check for "AnyType{}" :)

```
if (obj1.toString().equals("anyType{}")){
    strings.add("");
}
```

Just added this block of code below the else if.